# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{x^{2}\sin x}{8+\sin^{2}x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Prove that $$\int_{a}^{2a}f(x)dx = \int_{0}^{a}f(a+x)dx = \int_{0}^{a}f(2a-x)dx.$$
> Evaluate
> $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{x^{2}\sin x}{8+\sin^{2}x}dx.$$

I broke down the integral into
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{x^{2}\sin x}{8+\sin^{2}x}dx=\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{x^{2}\sin x}{8+\sin^{2}x}dx+\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{(\pi+x)^{2}\sin(\pi+x)}{8+\sin^{2}(\pi+x)}dx$$
or
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{x^{2}\sin x}{8+\sin^{2}x}dx=\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{x^{2}\sin x}{8+\sin^{2}x}dx+\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{(2\pi-x)^{2}\sin(2\pi-x)}{8+\sin^{2}(2\pi-x)}dx$$

But the answer is still zero. The actual answer for this is $$\frac{-2\pi^2}{3}\ln 2$$

Using Desmos Calculator, I come up with this.
[image]
[image]
[image]
Can anyone here to tell me how to do with this improper integral?

Comment: $$Consider \int udv = uv-\int vdu$$
$$Let u = x^{2}, du = 2xdx$$
$$dv = \frac{sinx}{8+sin^{2}x}dx$$
$$ v = \frac{-1}{6}\left[ \ln \frac{3+cosx}{3-cosx}\right]$$

Comment: This is not an improper integral: the integrand function $f(x)=\frac{x^{2}\sin x}{8+\sin^{2}x}$ is continuous on the whole interval $[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: @J_dash, I have completed my answer. Could you tell me if you like it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us start for instance from your first expression, and then make the change of variable $x=\frac\pi2+h,$ to take advantage of the nullity of the integral of an odd function over a symmetric interval:
$$\begin{align}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{x^2\sin x}{8+\sin^2x}dx&=\int_0^\pi\frac{x^2\sin x}{8+\sin^2x}dx+\int_0^\pi\frac{(\pi+x)^2\sin(\pi+x)}{8+\sin^2(\pi+x)}dx\\
&=\int_0^\pi\frac{(-2\pi x-\pi^2)\sin x}{8+\sin^2x}dx\\
&=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac{(-2\pi^2-2\pi h)\cos h}{8+\cos^2h}dh\\
&=-2\pi^2\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos h}{8+\cos^2h}dh\\
&=-2\pi^2\int_{-1}^1\frac{ds}{9-s^2}\\
&=-\frac{\pi^2}3\left[\ln\frac{3+s}{3-s}\right]_{-1}^1\\&=-\frac{2\pi^2}3\ln2.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Hi, Anne. Thank you so much for you answer. How do you know to pick $$x=\pi/2+h$$ to shift the function f(x) to left by $$\pi/2$$ to get rid of the nullity here? I examined this substitution for $$\int_{0}^{\pi}f(x)dx$$ here, the answer for $$\int_{0}^{\pi}f(x)dx$$ is zero. Can you tell me what's the integration rule for this kind of function?

Comment: To shift a function defined on $[a,b]$ so that the domain becomes symmetric, set $x:=\frac{a+b}2+h.$ $\int_0^{\pi}f(x)dx=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac{(\pi/2+h)^2\cos h}{8+\cos^2h}dh=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac{(\pi^2/4+h^2)\cos h}{8+\cos^2h}dh$ because $\frac{(\pi h)\cos h}{8+\cos^2h}$ is odd. This integral is not $0$ (the integrand is $>0$).

Comment: Sorry, Anne, I still can't work out the integral $$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac{\left (\frac{\pi^{2}}{4}+h^{2} \right )cosh}{8+cos^{2}h})dh$$. I broke it down into $$\frac{\pi^{2}}{4}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac{cosh}{8+cos^{2}h}dh + \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac{h^{2}cosh}{8+cos^{2}h}dh$$. The first one gave me $$\frac{\pi^{2}}{12}\ln2$$, and the second is zero.

Comment: I agree for the 1st one (like in my answer), but the 2nd one is $\ne0$ (the integrand is $>0$).

Comment: Anne, can you give me some clue to do the second one?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know, it seems complicated:  [indefinite integral](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+%28h%5E2+cos+h%29%2F%288%2Bcos%5E2+h%29+dh), [approximate value for the definite integral](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+%28h%5E2+cos+h%29%2F%288%2B+cos%5E2+h%29+dh+from+h%3D-pi%2F2+to+pi%2F2). Anyway, it was happily not needed to solve your problem.

Comment: Nevermind, Anne. Thank you so much for your inspiration by the way.

Answer (score 4):

By letting $\;t=\pi-x\;$ and $\;u=x-\pi\,,\;$ we get that

$\displaystyle\int_0^{2\pi}\!\!\!\frac{x^2\sin x}{8+\sin^2\!\!x}\mathrm dx=\!\int_0^{\pi}\!\!\frac{x^2\sin x}{8+\sin^2\!\!x}\mathrm dx+ \int_{\pi}^{2\pi}\!\!\frac{x^2\sin x}{8+\sin^2\!\!x}\mathrm dx=$

$=\displaystyle2\!\int_0^{\pi}\!\!\frac{x^2\!\sin x}{8\!+\!\sin^2\!\!x}\mathrm dx-\!\!\int_0^{\pi}\!\!\frac{x^2\!\sin x}{8\!+\!\sin^2\!\!x}\mathrm dx+\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}\!\!\frac{x^2\sin x}{8+\sin^2\!\!x}\mathrm dx=$

$=\displaystyle\!\!\!\!\int_0^{\!\pi}\!\frac{2x^2\!\sin x}{8\!+\!\sin^2\!\!x}\mathrm dx-\!\!\int_0^{\!\pi}\!\frac{(\pi\!-\!t)^2\!\sin t}{8\!+\!\sin^2\!t}\mathrm dt-\!\!\int_0^{\!\pi}\!\frac{(u\!+\!\pi)^2\!\sin u}{8\!+\!\sin^2\!u}\mathrm du=$

$=\displaystyle\!\!\!\!\int_0^{\!\pi}\!\frac{2x^2\!\sin x}{8\!+\!\sin^2\!\!x}\mathrm dx-\!\!\int_0^{\!\pi}\!\frac{(\pi\!-\!x)^2\!\sin x}{8\!+\!\sin^2\!\!x}\mathrm dx-\!\!\int_0^{\!\pi}\!\frac{(x\!+\!\pi)^2\!\sin x}{8\!+\!\sin^2\!\!x}\mathrm dx\!=$

$=\displaystyle\!\!\!\int_0^{\pi}\!\frac{\left[2x^2\!-\!(\pi\!-\!x)^2\!-\!(x\!+\!\pi)^2\right]\!\sin x}{8+\sin^2\!x}\,\mathrm dx=$

$=\displaystyle-2\pi^2\!\!\int_0^{\pi}\!\!\frac{\sin x}{8+\sin^2\!x}\,\mathrm dx=2\pi^2\!\!\int_0^{\pi}\!\!\frac{D(\cos x)}{9-\cos^2\!x}\,\mathrm dx=$

$=\displaystyle\frac{\pi^2}3\left[\ln\left(\frac{3+\cos x}{3-\cos x}\right)\right]_0^\pi=-\frac23\pi^2\!\ln2\,.$

Comment: Sorry, you can see the result from desmos is exactly same as $$\frac{-2\pi^{2}}{3}\ln2$$

Comment: Even GPT-4 can't solve it.

Comment: @J_dash I would not rely on ChatGPT for these types of calculations and proofs because it's an LLM meant to string words together as human-like as possible. It's not meant for math.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Angelo. But how do you pick the "correct" substitution for the integral?

Comment: @J_dash, my idea is based on eliminating the first degree term $\pi x$ which leads to a difficult integral by using the identity $(x+\pi)^2+(x-\pi)^2=2\left(x^2+\pi^2\right)$. In this way we get the original integral again (with the term $x^2$) and a simple integral (with the term $\pi^2$).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

After letting $x=t+\pi$, by symmetry, we note that
$$\begin{align}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{x^2\sin (x)}{8+\sin^2 (x)}\,dx&=-\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{(t+\pi)^2\sin (t)}{8+\sin^2 (t)}\,dt
=-2\pi\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{t\sin (t)}{8+\sin^2 (t)}\,dt\\&=-4\pi\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{t\sin (t)}{8+\sin^2 (t)}\,dt=-4\pi I=-\frac{2\pi^2}{3}\ln(2).
\end{align}$$
In order to evaluate $I$ let $t=\pi-s$:
$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{t\sin (t)}{8+\sin^2 (t)}\,dt=\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{(\pi-s)\sin (s)}{8+\sin^2 (s)}\,ds=\pi\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin (s)}{8+\sin^2 (s)}\,ds-I$$
which implies
$$\frac{2I}{\pi}=\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin (s)}{8+\sin^2 (s)}\,ds=-\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{D(\cos(s))}{9-\cos^2 (s)}\,ds=-\frac{1}{6}\left[\ln\left(\frac{3+\cos(s)}{3-\cos(s)}\right)\right]_0^\pi=\frac{\ln(2)}{3}.$$

Comment: Now I see, thank you

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Robert. I'm still working on how you made such substitution for x.

Comment: When $x=t+\pi$ then $\sin(x)=\sin(t+\pi)=-\sin(t)$, $dx=dt$ and the interval of integration becomes $[-\pi,\pi]$. Any more doubts?

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Letting $x\mapsto \pi-x$ yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{x^2 \sin x}{8+\sin ^2 x} d x = & \int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{(\pi-x)^2 \sin x}{8+\sin ^2 x} d x \\
= & \pi^2 \int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{\sin x}{8+\sin ^2 x} d x-2 \pi \int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{x \sin x}{8+\sin ^2 x} d x +\int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{x^2 \sin x}{8+\sin ^2 x} d x \\
= & -4 \pi \int_0^\pi \frac{x \sin x}{8+\sin ^2 x} d x \quad \textrm{ ( As the first and last integrands are odd.)}
\end{aligned}
$$
Integration by parts gives us
$$
\begin{aligned}\int_0^\pi \frac{x \sin x}{8+\sin ^2 x} d x = & -\frac{1}{6} \int_0^\pi x d\left(\ln \left(\frac{3+\cos x}{3-\cos x}\right)\right) \\
= & -\frac{1}{6}\left[x \ln \left(\frac{3+\cos x}{3-cos x} \right)\right]_0^\pi+\frac{1}{6}  \underbrace{ \int_0^\pi \ln \left(\frac{3+\cos x}{3-\cos x}\right) d x}_{=0 \quad  (\textrm{ By } x\mapsto \pi-x )}\\
= & \frac{1}{6} \pi \ln 2
\end{aligned}
$$
Now we can conclude that $$
\boxed{\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{x^2 \sin x}{8+\sin ^2 x} d x =-\frac{2 \pi^2}{3} \ln 2}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Integrate by parts:

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{x^2 \sin x}{8+\sin^2x} \, dx = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{x^2 \sin x}{9-\cos^2x} \, dx = \boxed{-\frac{2\pi^2}3 \ln2} - \frac13 \underbrace{\int_0^{2\pi} x \ln\frac{3-\cos x}{3+\cos x} \, dx}_{=0}$$

The remaining term vanishes since

$$\int_0^{2\pi} x \ln(3\pm\cos x) \, dx \stackrel{x\mapsto2\pi-x}= \int_0^{2\pi} (2\pi-x) \ln(3\pm\cos x) \, dx \\
\implies 2 \int_0^{2\pi} x \ln(3\pm\cos x) \, dx \stackrel{x\mapsto x+\pi}= 2\pi \int_{-\pi}^\pi \ln(3\mp\cos x) \, dx$$